# Преобразование строки в массив | PHP | JS

Tags: javascript, php, парсер

Есть вот такая сложная **строка**:

```
[2,3], [['https://h8.rmr.rocks/','',"auto/54/43/58/001___________.png?t=1641084571&u=0&h=KiNURRSNRlWIHRfawmjv6Q",720,10706],['https://h38.rmr.rocks/','',"auto/54/43/58/002___________.png?t=1641084571&u=0&h=N3ncSIbn_PLRi-GpCme0vQ",720,11167],['https://h27.rmr.rocks/','',"auto/54/43/58/003___________.png?t=1641084571&u=0&h=vupT5VUvHQ6j1liMt6NF0A",720,12237],['https://h32.rmr.rocks/','',"auto/54/43/58/004___________.png?t=1641084571&u=0&h=hSbWgf646fK0fYKWksxaAA",720,13222],['https://h27.rmr.rocks/','',"auto/54/43/58/005___________.png?t=1641084571&u=0&h=vvcK12ZIA8wEnDcHcrKZWQ",720,12709],['https://h38.rmr.rocks/','',"auto/54/43/58/006___________.png?t=1641084571&u=0&h=-knVcY8GQpmTgw3XImiGIQ",720,12747],['https://h8.rmr.rocks/','',"auto/54/43/58/007___________.png?t=1641084571&u=0&h=yr5xwhHI_7_rcBsS8r6oVA",720,11670],['https://h32.rmr.rocks/','',"auto/54/43/58/008___________.png?t=1641084571&u=0&h=BDXPbLoAE58iwsYgH7u_ZQ",720,12414],['https://h24.rmr.rocks/','',"auto/54/43/58/009___________.png?t=1641084571&u=0&h=87VP6YSArvidx1wz0SXvFg",720,12251],['https://h37.rmr.rocks/','',"auto/54/43/58/010___________.png?t=1641084571&u=0&h=IIVF7DiFt3eoEx1X-LfILQ",716,7473],['https://h32.rmr.rocks/','',"auto/54/43/58/011___________.png_res.jpg?t=1641084571&u=0&h=vmYoIIEzU2uLm8dy5Qc51A",1920,1080]], 0, false, [{"path":"https://h32.rmr.rocks/","res":true},{"path":"https://h37.rmr.rocks/","res":true},{"path":"https://h8.rmr.rocks/","res":true},{"path":"https://h40.rmr.rocks/","res":true},{"path":"https://h27.rmr.rocks/","res":true},{"path":"https://h30.rmr.rocks/","res":true},{"path":"https://h42.rmr.rocks/","res":true},{"path":"https://h24.rmr.rocks/","res":true},{"path":"https://h31.rmr.rocks/","res":true},{"path":"https://h38.rmr.rocks/","res":true},{"path":"https://h34.rmr.rocks/","res":true}], false
```

Нужно её как-то с помощью **PHP или JS** преобразовать **в массив**.

**ВАЖНО:** в массив должны попадать лишь те данные, где параметры **НЕ** объекты.

**Пример:** `['https://h8.rmr.rocks/','',"auto/54/43/58/001___________.png?t=1641084571&u=0&h=KiNURRSNRlWIHRfawmjv6Q",720,10706]` - попадет в массив, `[{"path":"https://h32.rmr.rocks/","res":true},{"path":"https://h37.rmr.rocks/","res":true}]` - не попадет в массив.

Пытался делать через PHP так, но это не очень эффективно, т.к. иногда две ссылки слипаются в одну:

```
$data = [];

preg_match_all('/\[\[(.*?)\]\]/is', $current_js, $_data);

    foreach ($_data as $key => $value) {
        if (count($value) > 0) {
            $firstData = substr($value[0], 0, 1) === '[';

            if ($firstData) {
                $value = substr($value[0], 1, -1);

                $images = explode(',', $value);
                $old = '';

                foreach ($images as $key2 => $valData) {
                    $valData = str_replace('[', '', $valData);
                    $valData = str_replace(']', '', $valData);
                    $valData = str_replace("''", '', $valData);

                    if (strlen($valData) > 0 && !is_numeric($valData)) {
                        $valData = str_replace("'", '', $valData);
                        $valData = str_replace('"', '', $valData);

                        preg_match_all('/https:\/\//is', $valData, $dda);

                        if (count($dda[0]) > 0) {
                            $old = $valData;
                            if (!array_key_exists($old, $data['images'])) $data['images'][$old] = '';
                        }

                        $data['images'][$old] .= $valData;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Можно ли как-то регуляркой вытащить нужные мне данные? Или есть другой способ?

Comment: `json_decode` вы этому добру не пробовали делать?

Comment: @teran, строка не валидна для json_decode, поэтому даже не пытался. А функция может и такие строки тоже обрабатывать? Там ведь нет ключей по большей части.

Comment: там где нет ключей это массив. тут если всю строку обернуть в `[]` то она декодируется вполне

Answer (score 0):

Смог решить задачу следующим способом:

```
preg_match_all("#(['|\"]((.*?)\.(?:png|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg)(.*?))['|\"])#is", $current_js, $links);

$_links = [];

foreach ($links as $key => $value) {
    $_value = preg_replace("#\'|\"|\,|\s+#is", '', $value);

    foreach ($_value as $k => $v) {
        preg_match_all("#(http)?s?:?(\/\/[^\"']*\.(?:png|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg))#is", $v, $vl);

        if(count($vl[0]) > 0) {
           array_push($_links, $v);
        }
    }
}

$valid_links = array_unique($_links);
$data['images'] = $valid_links;
```

Сначала мы получаем все, что похоже на массив с ссылкой: `preg_match_all("#(['|\"]((.*?)\.(?:png|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg)(.*?))['|\"])#is", $current_js, $links);`

После этого удаляем из результата все запятые, скобки и т.п. `$_value = preg_replace("#\'|\"|\,|\s+#is", '', $value);`

Далее проверяем валидность ссылки на изображение (из-за кривой регулярки попадает в массив и .png, и https://.../__ (без окончания .png и т.п.)): `preg_match_all("#(http)?s?:?(\/\/[^\"']*\.(?:png|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg))#is", $v, $vl);`

Добавляем в массив: `array_push($_links, $v);` и фильтруем по уникальности: `$valid_links = array_unique($_links);`.

Я не очень хорошо разбираюсь в регулярках, так что, если кто-то знает, как сделать лучше, то напишите в комментарии.